# Unable to assign a value

Tags: c++

i am a newbie to c++ language.
I am using code lite to code.
it's my code here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int age1;
int age2;   
    cout<<"Enter Age of First Kid";
    cin >> age1;
        cout<<"Enter Age of Second Kid";
cin>>age2;
}
```

But it's giving me this error

```
C:/myWorkspace/practise/main.cpp:8:2: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
```

Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there's a hello world example out there you can modify to do this

Comment: Probably because you did not read your C++ book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add `using namespace std;` before `main` to make this work.

Note: this may cause problems in some situations. Here it's OK.

Moreover, you're using a wrong header. Use `<iostream>` instead of `<stdio.h>`.

---

This will work

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int age1;
int age2;   
cout<<"Enter Age of First Kid";
cin >> age1;
cout<<"Enter Age of Second Kid";
cin>>age2;

return 0; // it's better to inform the system everything's OK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int age1;
    int age2;   
    std::cout<<"Enter Age of First Kid";
    std::cin >> age1;
    std::cout<<"Enter Age of Second Kid";
    std::cin>>age2;
}
```